# How to use regex on date to extract entry by year?

Tags: python, mongodb

My entries in MongoDB have a publishedDate field as follows:
`publishedDate:"{'$date': '1999-08-01T00:00:00.000-0700'}"`

How do I retrieve the entries via collection.find with $regex, using user's input for year?

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB version >= 4.4 we can write custom filters using [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator so try this:

```js
let yearRegex = /^1999/;

db.testCollection.find({
    $expr: {
        $function: {
            body: function(publishedDate, yearRegex) {
                return yearRegex.test(publishedDate);
            },
            args: [{ $toString: "$publishedDate" }, yearRegex],
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: Instead of [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) we can also use [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) with `timezone` to cover edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

`"{'$date': '1999-08-01T00:00:00.000-0700'}"` looks like MongoDB extended JSON notation for a Datetime object.

If the data in the collection is actually a date, note that the timezone in the database will be UTC, so the start/end would be off by a few hours if you intended to use any other timezone.

You can build a date object for the beginning of the year, and another for the beginning of the following year, and query for dates between:

```
let queryYear = 1999

db.collection.find({
         publishedDate:{
            $gte: new Date( queryYear + "-01-01T00:00:00-0700" ), 
            $lt: new Date( (queryYear+1) + "-01-01T00:00:00-0700") 
}})
```

This allows to you build a date object with the desired timezone, and this query could also make use of an index on the publishedDate field.